# KeyError: 'formatters' in logging module

Tags: python, logging, keyerror

I have been having trouble loading a `logging` config file. This is my first time using `logging`, and I am basing it off [another project](https://github.com/mhallsmoore/qsforex/blob/master/trading/trading.py). Here's what I have:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('C:/....../FX_Base/trading/logging.conf',
                          disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger('FX_Base.trading.trading')
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/............./FX_Base/trading/trading.py", line 57, in <module>
    disable_existing_loggers=False)
  File "C:\.............Python\Python35\lib\logging\config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "C:\.....\Python\Python35\lib\logging\config.py", line 109, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "C:\.......\Python\Python35\lib\configparser.py", line 956, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

I don't understand what the issue is. I've searched the site and it seems that the issue might be in finding the directory, but I have it pretty specific.

Comment: Does `C:/....../` exist as a directory?

Comment: Yes, it's the exact same directory where I am running my program. (I am running in trading/trading.py and trying to put my config in trading/logging.conf)

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not too great at Python, could you explain how I could check my work as per the solution in that link?

Comment: Try throwing in some `print`s like `print(os.getcwd())` or similar. Those may help diagnose the situation. That `print` in particular will allow you to verify where the working directory, which may not be what you think it is.

Comment: the directories all seem to be in order..

Comment: @Hoodtingz did you find answer to this ... If so could you please share the solution?